# PHPMailer Foreach Loop

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer

I currently am using PHPMailer which gets the list of email addresses from an uploaded .txt file. The current system works fine, but I am trying to add a tracking system to see if the email is viewed.

We are doing this by adding an image to each email which when viewed updates via php to let us know the email has been viewed.

Currently our PHPMail looks something like this,

```
foreach ($email_addresses as $line_num => $line) {
            $ismatch = preg_match('/^[\s,]+$/',$line);
            $isvalid = preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', trim($line));

            // found a blank line, ignore
            if($ismatch)
                echo "";

            // found an invaid email address, add to string
            else if($isvalid==0)
                $strInvalidEmailAddresses .= $line. '<br />';

            // no issues, add to BCC
            else{
                $mail->addBCC($line,$line); 
            }
}
```

The current system adds each email to BCC. I would like each email to be sent to each individual address without BCCing them.

I ran into issues when I tried this image to the end of the HTML email.

```
$track_image = '<img src="http://domain.com/email_test/email_beacon.php?campaign='.$intCampaignID.'&email='.$line.'" alt="" />';

$mail->MsgHTML($html_page.$track_image);
```

Whenever I try to include the tracking image, the $line (or email) is always the same, but I need it to change depending on which emails are in the .txt file.

Comment: Keep in mind that most email clients (web/desktop based) block loading remote content by default.

Comment: I understand this, not saying it's a 100% solution, but it will at least let us know for some of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using BCC, you'd do something like:

```
... initialize PHP mailer ...
... set options common to ALL emails ...
foreach( ... loop over all recipients ...) {
    $mail->ClearAddresses(); // remove previous email addresses
    $mail->AddAddress($new_recipient_here);
    $mail->Body = <<<EOL
... customized html here
<img src="http://domain.com/email_test/email_beacon.php?campaign={$intCampaignID}&email={$address}" alt="" />
... more html here
EOL;

    $mail->send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My .txt file has 2 emails for my test. The last email in the file gets two emails and the first one gets sent one as it should. I think this is because of the $mail->send(); But removing it only sends  the email to the last one on the file. I'm not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Use `ClearAllRecipients()` to clears all recipients assigned in the TO, CC and BCC array. It returns void.

Answer (score 0):

The second issue is simply a forgotten $ -- it looks like your current example would throw a parse error. It should be:

```
$mail->MsgHTML($html_page.$track_image);
```

In order to send individual emails, instead of sending one email with a bunch of BCC's, you'd need to create a new $mail object each time inside the loop, instead of appending them all to a single $mail object which was already defined outside the loop.

Comment: I did have the $ on my original file, but accidentally removed it on the copy and paste when I put it on here.